# Convert Rows to columns with Pivot in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have following table with data:

```
date            Plant          Weight
2017-11-11  Gent        26
2017-11-11  Ang         25
2017-11-11  Ger         24
2017-11-11  ISS         23
2017-11-10  Gent        26
2017-11-10  Ang         25
2017-11-11  Ger         24
2017-11-11  ISS         23
2017-11-11  Gent        12
2017-11-11  Ang         13
2017-11-10  Gent        100
```

I would like it to come out as a pivot table, like this:

```
datum           Ang Gent  Ger  ISS
2017-11-10      25  126   0    0
2017-11-11      38   38  48   46
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried a query yet.  Google for "SQL pivot query," and you will find tons of resources which can help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
PIVOT
(
   MAX(Weight) FOR [Plant] IN ([Ang], [Gent], [Ger], [ISS])
) PVT;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you could use of Conditional `case` expression condition if you don't want to go with `Pivot` operator

```
SELECT DATE [datum],
          SUM(CASE(PLANT) WHEN 'Ang' THEN Weight ELSE NULL END) [Ang],
          SUM(CASE(PLANT) WHEN 'Gent' THEN Weight ELSE NULL END) [Gent],
          SUM(CASE(PLANT) WHEN 'Ger' THEN Weight ELSE 0 END) [Ger],
          SUM(CASE(PLANT) WHEN 'ISS' THEN Weight ELSE 0 END) [ISS]
FROM <table> GROUP BY [DATE]
```

Other one is dynamic `pivot` way if you are not satisfied with conditional `case` expression

```
DECLARE @Col NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Col = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ','+QUOTENAME(PLANT) FROM <table> FOR XML PATH('')),1,1, '')

SET @Query = N'SELECT * FROM <table> 
                    PIVOT
                    (
                       sum(Weight) FOR [Plant] IN ('+@Col+')
                    ) PVT'

execute sp_executesql @Query
```

Result :

```
datum           Ang Gent  Ger  ISS
2017-11-10      25  126   0    0
2017-11-11      38   38  48   46
```

Comment: The 'non-dynamic conditional case expression' solves my problem well but how can you create totals row- and columnwise?

Answer (score 0):

```
select [datum],[Gent],[Ang],[ISS],[Ger],[Gent]+[Angouleme]+[ISS]+[Gerona] as [TOTAAL] FROM (select plant,datum,sum(weight) as weight FROM [MEPDARPD].[dbo].[Table1]  group by plant,datum)t
PIVOT
(
sum(Weight) 
FOR [Plant] IN ([Gent],[Ang],[ISS],[Ger])
) AS p
```

Below the query with totals in rows and columns

---

```
select datum,
sum(case(plant) WHEN 'Ang' then weight else 0 END) as [Ang],
sum(case(plant) WHEN 'Gent' then weight else 0 END) as [Gent],
sum(case(plant) WHEN 'ISS' then weight else 0 END) as [ISS],
sum(case(plant) WHEN 'Ger' then weight else 0 END) as [Ger],
SUM(weight) as total
from MEPDARPD.dbo.rous group by datum
with rollup
```

That query solves my problem. Thanks for the help.